# Problems with explicit wait and implicit wait in Selenium Webdriver (Selenium 2) using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have to work with some really slow proxies and got stuck every now and then. Therefore I'm trying to find a solution/workaround for this, here's my problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://whateversite.com")

element = browser.find_element_by_id("element")
element.click() # go to page http://whateversite.com/page.html

new_element = browser.find_element_by_id("newElement")
```

No matter if you set up `browser.implicitly_wait(30)` before hand or use `new_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until（lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id("newElement"))` It just stuck, sometimes for HOURS. It seems to wait for that page `http://whateversite.com/page.html` to fully load up which in some extreme cases that could take hours.

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: What actual browser are you using? Does it make a difference if you use Firefox or Chrome? Your code looks like it should work. What happens when you visit these sites by hand?

Comment: @H.Dunlop: Firefox, sorry I just corrected the codes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell me why this does not end up with a timeout error (selenium 2 webdriver)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757061/tell-me-why-this-does-not-end-up-with-a-timeout-error-selenium-2-webdriver)

Comment: Can you actually provide the page that is causing the problem, or is it every page?  Webdriver does not return until the page is completely loaded.  Some solutions are usually to disable third party related crap when you use selenium to avoid this, see this as an example: http://element34.ca/blog/get-rid-of-the-3rd-party-crap

Answer (score 0):

try to use unstable load strategy.
For example`FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();`
`profile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");`
`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);` `
You can find more information at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#current-document-readiness

Also try this. driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a good answer to this problem, so I thought I'd give my solution. I've encountered this many times working with selenium and as hack-y as it is, I use expect.  expect is a really simple tcl-based language that lets you easily spawn other programs and wait for input or timeout and do something.  so basically instead of using sel's waits, i create a function that uses python's sleep to wait:

```
import time

def wait(waittime=30):
  print 'kick'
  time.sleep(waittime)

..
```

then I create run.exp:

```
set timeout 30
set try 0

while 1 {
    spawn /usr/bin/python test.py
        while 1 {
            expect "kick" {exp_continue}
            timeout {
                if {$try > 5} {
                    exit
                }
                incr try
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thats all and it usually works really well, basically it will try to restart the program if it hangs.  After 5 tries it kills itself.  You could also have more controls as to how to re-start your program in different states etc.

Comment: `import time` is required for this **time function** to use with Selenium Python