# Tell me why this does not end up with a timeout error (selenium 2 webdriver)?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("http://testsite.com")

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id("element"))

element.click() # it actually goes to page http://testsite.com/test-page.html

print "Just clicked! And I'm expecting timeout error!"

new_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 0.1).until(lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id("element"))

print "Too bad there's no timeout error, why?!"
```

OK, as you can see even I set wait time to 0.1 sec there's still no timeout exception thrown. When `element.click()` executed it does not block till the whole page loads up and that's why `Just clicked! And I'm expecting timeout error!` showed up, and to my surprise `new_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 0.1).until(lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id("element"))` wait till the whole page loads up. And if you use `implicit waits`, you get the same result.

My point is, sometimes after you click an element it might take up to even hours for a page to load up because of a bad proxy, and you obviously **DO NOT** want to wait that long, what you want is a timeout exception. In this case how would you make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Clicks have an implicit wait built into them to wait for when the page is loaded. There is work, currently complete in FirefoxDriver only, that allows you to set how long Selenium should wait for a page to load.

This will probably be in Selenium 2.22 for Python and then your test case will likely fail once that is set

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. Would you please be more specific and how can I do that?

Comment: ... and upon upgrading to 2.22, I realized all the places where I unknowingly relied on this implicit wait. XD

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. You are talking about driver.set_page_load_timeout() I believe, however that doesn't have to do with clicks. Not all clicks trigger a page load. The page load time out is just for page loading. Questioner is also having trouble with the timeout on simply finding the element (no clicks need be involved).

Answer (score 0):

The Until method on webdriver wait ignores the element not found exception and other exceptions which occures in the condition you specify, for the time period you specify. After the given time, you would initially be getting a no such element exception if you dont have the element present and then a timeout exception if you handle the 'no such element' exception(preferably in a try catch).

For your need you could try a work around this way-

-> Bring the focus to the button after which there is a page load
-> Fire the click with java code(not webdriver. since clicks will wait for the next page to load.)
-> Put a thread.sleep for a second or two
-> check for the element's prescense.

Comment: I totally understand your work around, thanks mate! But from what I see the problem kinda lives with `browser.find_element_by_id("idstuff")` too, which means it does NOT actually start to check for that element's presence until that page is fully loaded up, I don't know what point is in this mechanism, but this bugs me a lot as you have no control over this.

Comment: If you haven't already tried this, you could see if you get something here.(esp comment 4 sounded promising)of this link http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=687. Came up after a random search. No gauranties :) –